# Not able to share a file (via Gmail or Google Drive)

Tags: android

I have the following code to share a file.

It all seems to work fine,

Gmail opens with the attachment attached,

but when I click SEND Gmail stops and gives an error `Unfortunately Gmail has stopped`

The same with Google Drive, all seems to work fine but in the end I get: 
`Upload failed` by Google drive.

Any help very much appreciated!!!

```
share.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            fileuri=Utility.downloadDb(MainActivity.this);
            if(fileuri!=null){
                Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
                sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, fileuri);
                startActivity(sharingIntent);
            }
        }
    });
```

Where `Utility.downloadDb(MainActivity.this);`
is:

```
public static Uri downloadDb(Context context) {
    DatabaseHandler db= new DatabaseHandler(context);
    ArrayList<Word> list=new ArrayList<Word>();
    Uri fileuri=null;
    list.clear();
    list.addAll(db.getAllWords());
    File path = Environment
            .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
    File file = new File(path, "db.csv");
    try {
        file.createNewFile();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        // Make sure the Pictures directory exists.
        path.mkdirs();

        FileWriter outFile = new FileWriter(file);
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(outFile);
        out.print("PICTURE NAME");
        out.print(",");
        out.print("WORD NUMBER");
        out.print(",");
        out.print("LEFT");
        out.print(",");
        out.print("TOP");
        out.print(",");
        out.print("RIGHT");
        out.print(",");
        out.println("BOTTOM");

        for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
            out.print(list.get(i).pic);
            out.print(",");
            out.print(Integer.toString(list.get(i).wordno));
            out.print(",");
            out.print(Integer.toString(list.get(i).beginx));
            out.print(",");
            out.print(Integer.toString(list.get(i).beginy));
            out.print(",");
            out.print(Integer.toString(list.get(i).endx));
            out.print(",");
            out.println(Integer.toString(list.get(i).endy));


        }

        out.close();
        Toast.makeText(context, "SAVED TO: " +file.getAbsolutePath(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        fileuri=Uri.parse(file.getAbsolutePath());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Unable to create file, likely because external storage is
        // not currently mounted.
        Log.e("ExternalStorage", "Error writing " + file, e);
    }
    return fileuri;
}
```

Comment: can you find and open the file? (and maybe try to share it 'manually', just to see what happens...?)

Comment: @jpm thanks jpm the file gets created and can be sent "manually" via Gmail

Comment: mhh. I don't know whether there is a difference, but maybe try Uri.fromFile(file) instead of Uri.parse()...that's how I do it, and it works...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution found!!!!

**I think this might be useful for other people as well!!!**

to get the URI use:
`fileuri=Uri.fromFile(file);`

NOT
fileuri=Uri.parse(file.getAbsolutePath());